# productsRequest in apple review return nil

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

I have configured IAP in my app correctly, and it works in debug when I install from TestFlight too, but the problem is my App rejected in apple review because "productsRequest" probably return 0, I really dont know how it possible... I wrote to Apple technician but still they didn't respond.
Any idea?

Comment: Have you fully configured the products? (set the price and everything)

Comment: YES, the tear price in TestFlight shows different and I submitted bug to apple and they said that they will resolve it as soon as possible. When I install app from TestFlight and in debug Xcode IAP purchase works correctly but in apple review sandbox it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem? My products are displayed normally locally. But there are no products in testflight

Comment: Apple passed my app because it was their bug. if It doesn't show in TestFlight probably it is your bug. please share your code.